# JUnit: Ignore method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I know using JUnit that it is possible to ignore a test using the @Ignore annotation but is it possible to ignore a method call from all JUnit tests if the method is called from another method?

In the example below i want to be able to test the `createPerson(...)` method but i want my test to ignore the `createAddress(...)` method

**Quick Example : Person.java**

```
public void createPerson(...){
    createAddress(...);
    createBankAccount(...);
    ...
}

@IgnoreByTests
public void createAddress(...){
... creates address ...
}

public void createBankAccount(...)[
... creates bank account ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into mocking the methods you don't want to invoke. Take a look at [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for pretty useful mocking framework.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "ignoring a method"? How would the function that uses it work during tests? Maybe you mean `mocking` as suggested by @Henrik above, but you formulate the idea in a quite strange way.

Comment: i know it is a strange request alright, using a mocking framework is it possible to actually mock a method call but not the entire call itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your testing class:

```
Person p = Mockito.spy(new Person());
```

[Spying in Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html)

How does that work:

> You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the
>   real methods are called (unless a method was stubbed). Real spies
>   should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when dealing
>   with legacy code.
>
> Spying on real objects can be associated with "partial mocking"
>   concept. Before the release 1.8, Mockito spies were not real partial
>   mocks. The reason was we thought partial mock is a code smell. At some
>   point we found legitimate use cases for partial mocks (3rd party
>   interfaces, interim refactoring of legacy code, the full article is
>   [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13))

```
   List list = new LinkedList();
   List spy = spy(list);

   //optionally, you can stub out some methods:
   when(spy.size()).thenReturn(100);

   //using the spy calls real methods
   spy.add("one");
   spy.add("two");

   //prints "one" - the first element of a list
   System.out.println(spy.get(0));

   //size() method was stubbed - 100 is printed
   System.out.println(spy.size());

   //optionally, you can verify
   verify(spy).add("one");
   verify(spy).add("two");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is when mocking comes into the picture. For example, Mockito:

```
class Tests {
 private Mock<MyClass> mockedClass;
 @Setup
 void Setup(){
  mockedClass = new Mock<MyClass>();
 }

 @Test
 void MyMockedTest(){
  Mockito.when(mockedClass.createAddress()).thenReturn("Some address 15, USA");
 }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mock the class you are testing. For that goal you have `spy`, eventhough it is not really recommendable

Comment: Considering you say that `spy` isn't recommendable: what's the downside of mocking the entire class?

Comment: The object that you are testing should never be mocked, just because it is the object that you are testing and you want to test it, not to mock it. Spying objects is just a trick done for using when you have no other way to solve your problem but it should be avoided. If you have to spy it will probably mean that you have something that can be improved.

Comment: I still don't see any arguments why you shouldn't mock the entire class. What are the negative consequences?

Comment: First: you want to test it, not to mock it. Second: if you mock it, you mock the whole class (methods), how are you going to test it if you have mocked it and they do nothing?. Third: Mocking is used for "simulating" behavior of external classes, classes that are not going to be tested and we don't want to test. Fourth: if mocking the object to test were a good thing `spy` would never exists, as I said it was developed to avoid having to mock the whole object when you just need to mock one method. Fifth: mocking an object returns a subclass so you don't test the actual one, and so on